# Three-Column layer alignment

Tags: html, css, layout, sticky-footer

Ok, I have spent the last week trying to do this on my own. I swear I have visited EVERY Google page available.

My original problem was that my three-column layer was stacked.
After coming upon a similiar question on this site, I was able to get my footer to split into three columns with the float technique.

However, it is at an angle: 
Like, column one is where I want ALL of them to be. 
I will post my CSS and HTML.

I am VERY new at this, and all of you will probably puke at how bad my code is.  BUT, this is why i'm coming to you.  I need help, because I just can't do this alone.

You can view the website I am working on here. http://www.bbcardmore.com/

```
.left{
text-align:left;
float:left;
}
.right{
float:right;
text-align:right;
}
.centered{
text-align:center;
}

<?php?>
<html>
<body>
<head>
</style>
   <head>
    <div id="footer">
     <div class="left">
     <h3><p style="padding-top: 10pt; " class="paragraph_style"><font size="5" color="red">About Us</font><br /></p></h3>
         <p class="paragraph_style_1"><a title="Our History" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/bbc-history-3/">Our History</a>                 <br /></p>
         <p class="paragraph_style_1"><a title="Our Pastor" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/our-pastor/">Our Pastor</a><br />  </p>
         <p class="paragraph_style_1"><a title="Statement Of Faith" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/statement-of- faith/">Statement Of Faith</a><br /></p>
         <p class="paragraph_style_1"><a title="Calendar" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/calendar/">Calendar</a><br /></p>
         <p style="padding-bottom: 0pt; " class="paragraph_style_1"><a title="Map"  href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/map/">Map</a></p>

     <div class="centered">
     <h3><p style="padding-top: 10pt; " class="paragraph_style"><a title="Service Times" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/service-times/"><font size="5" color="red">Service Times</font><br /></p></h3>
         <p class="paragraph_style_1"><a title="Service Times" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/service-times/"> Sunday School~ 10:00</a><br /></p>
         <p class="paragraph_style_1"><a title="Service Times" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/service-times/"> Sunday Morning Service~ 11:00 AM</a><br /></p>
         <p class="paragraph_style_1"><a title="Service Times" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/service-times/"> Sunday Evening Service~ 7:00 PM</a><br /></p>
         <p class="paragraph_style_1"><a title="Service Times" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/service-times/"> Wednesday Evening Bible Study~ 7:00 PM</a><br /></p>
         <p class="paragraph_style_1"><a title="Service Times" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/service-times/"> Transportation and child care available for all services.</a><br /></p>

       <div class="right">
    <h3><p style="padding-top: 10pt; " class="paragraph_style"><a title="Contact Us" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/contact-us/"><font size="5" color="red">Contact Us:</font><br /></p></h3>
        <p class="paragraph_style_2"><a title="Map" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/map/"><font size="3" color="red">Mailing Address:</font><br /></p>
        <p class="paragraph_style_1"><a title="Map" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/map/">1515 Easley Drive<br /></p>
        <p class="paragraph_style_1"><a title="Map" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/map/">Ardmore, OK 73401<br /></p>
        <p class="paragraph_style_3"><span class="style"><a title="" href="mailto:bbcardmore@aol.com"><font size="3" color="red">Email:</font></span> bbcardmore@aol.com<br /></p>
        <p class="paragraph_style_3"><span class="style"><a title="Contact Us" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/contact-us/"><font size="3" color="red">Phone:</font></span> (580) 223-6629<br /></p>

      <div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hi, pls use correct tags - see what I added.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry.  This is my first post.  and it said that I couldn't put in new tags.  I got confused, and only put in one.  Thank-you for correcting me.

Comment: As far as the question goes.  I am realizing a lot of mistakes, because I put this in jsFiddle.
Still not getting the effect I want.  But at least i'm cleaning up the  code.

Comment: so you want 3 column aligned horizontally right?

Comment: Those who are still using <font> tag should be banished from stackoverflow, in the name of holy internetz elders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking like this demo : - http://tinkerbin.com/N87sxG5i

Actually you didn't close your child div's like : `left, Center, Right` so i closed the these child div's and after that i gave `float:left;`to your `center div` rather than text-align:center; to that div and its working fine now as per your requirement....

**HTML**

```
<html>
<body>
<head>
</style>
   <head>
    <div id="footer">
     <div class="left">
     <h3><p style="padding-top: 10pt; " class="paragraph_style"><font size="5" color="red">About Us</font><br /></p></h3>
         <p class="paragraph_style_1"><a title="Our History" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/bbc-history-3/">Our History</a>                 <br /></p>
         <p class="paragraph_style_1"><a title="Our Pastor" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/our-pastor/">Our Pastor</a><br />  </p>
         <p class="paragraph_style_1"><a title="Statement Of Faith" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/statement-of- faith/">Statement Of Faith</a><br /></p>
         <p class="paragraph_style_1"><a title="Calendar" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/calendar/">Calendar</a><br /></p>
         <p style="padding-bottom: 0pt; " class="paragraph_style_1"><a title="Map"  href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/map/">Map</a></p>
            </div>  

     <div class="centered">
     <h3><p style="padding-top: 10pt; " class="paragraph_style"><a title="Service Times" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/service-times/"><font size="5" color="red">Service Times</font><br /></p></h3>
         <p class="paragraph_style_1"><a title="Service Times" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/service-times/"> Sunday School~ 10:00</a><br /></p>
         <p class="paragraph_style_1"><a title="Service Times" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/service-times/"> Sunday Morning Service~ 11:00 AM</a><br /></p>
         <p class="paragraph_style_1"><a title="Service Times" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/service-times/"> Sunday Evening Service~ 7:00 PM</a><br /></p>
         <p class="paragraph_style_1"><a title="Service Times" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/service-times/"> Wednesday Evening Bible Study~ 7:00 PM</a><br /></p>
         <p class="paragraph_style_1"><a title="Service Times" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/service-times/"> Transportation and child care available for all services.</a><br /></p>
                </div>

       <div class="right">
    <h3><p style="padding-top: 10pt; " class="paragraph_style"><a title="Contact Us" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/contact-us/"><font size="5" color="red">Contact Us:</font><br /></p></h3>
        <p class="paragraph_style_2"><a title="Map" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/map/"><font size="3" color="red">Mailing Address:</font><br /></p>
        <p class="paragraph_style_1"><a title="Map" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/map/">1515 Easley Drive<br /></p>
        <p class="paragraph_style_1"><a title="Map" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/map/">Ardmore, OK 73401<br /></p>
        <p class="paragraph_style_3"><span class="style"><a title="" href="mailto:bbcardmore@aol.com"><font size="3" color="red">Email:</font></span> bbcardmore@aol.com<br /></p>
        <p class="paragraph_style_3"><span class="style"><a title="Contact Us" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/contact-us/"><font size="3" color="red">Phone:</font></span> (580) 223-6629<br /></p>
            </div>

      <div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

**CSS**

```
.left{
text-align:left;
float:left;
}
.right{
float:right;
text-align:right;
}
.centered{
float:left;
margin-left:25px;
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU!  The service times are a little bit to the left, but I think I can manage that!  THANK YOU SOOOOOO MUCH!

Comment: Ok, thanks to all of you for all of your help.  If I ever need any help again, I am coming STRAIGHT here. 
Thanks to Shailender Arora especially though.  The code you gave was perfect.  I just edited the margins and centered the text. 
And though this is probably the ugliest looking footer know to man.  It works for what I need it to work for, as of right now.
<3

Comment: most welcome @Owlman113 and welcome on Stackoverflow its good platform to learn and share the knowledge  and you can get & give the solutions of web issues...........

Answer (score 1):

I m not sure but it may work...
Try this code..

```
.left{
float:left;
}
.right{
float:left;
}
.centered{
float:left;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but all that did was make the text stacked like a tower again.

Comment: try this..
    .left{
    float:left; width:25%;
    }
    .right{
    float:left; width:50%;
    }
    .centered{
    float:left;  width:25%;
    }

Answer (score 0):

You need to correctly format your tags, close all tags you open to avoid nesting errors.

Floating is tricky business, and floated elements need to be placed before elements that are to flow around them.

Your markup should be formatted like this:

```
<div class="center">
    <div class="left">
        <p class="red-title">About Us</p>
        <p><a title="Our History" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/bbc-history-3/">Our History</a></p>
        <p><a title="Our Pastor" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/our-pastor/">Our Pastor</a></p>
        <p><a title="Statement Of Faith" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/statement-of- faith/">Statement Of Faith</a></p>
        <p><a title="Calendar" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/calendar/">Calendar</a></p>
        <p><a title="Map"  href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/map/">Map</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <p class="red-title"><a title="Contact Us" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/contact-us/">Contact Us:</a></p>
        <p><a title="Map" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/map/"><span class="red">Mailing Address:</span></a></p>
        <p><a title="Map" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/map/">1515 Easley Drive</a></p>
        <p><a title="Map" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/map/">Ardmore, OK 73401</a></p>
        <p><a title="Email" href="mailto:bbcardmore@aol.com"><span class="red">Email:</span> bbcardmore@aol.com</a></p>
        <p><a title="Contact Us" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/contact-us/"><span class="red">Phone:</span> (580) 223-6629</a></p>
    </div>
    <p class="red-title"><a title="Service Times" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/service-times/">Service Times</a></p>
    <p><a title="Service Times" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/service-times/">Sunday School~ 10:00</a></p>
    <p><a title="Service Times" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/service-times/">Sunday Morning Service~ 11:00 AM</a></p>
    <p><a title="Service Times" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/service-times/">Sunday Evening Service~ 7:00 PM</a></p>
    <p><a title="Service Times" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/service-times/">Wednesday Evening Bible Study~ 7:00 PM</a></p>
    <p><a title="Service Times" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/service-times/">Transportation and child care available for all services.</a></p>
</div>
```

This CSS sheet will transform this markup into the three column design you're after:

```
.left {
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
}
.right {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
}
.center {
    text-align: center;
}
.red-title {
    color: #e00;
    font-size: 180%;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.red {
    color: #e00;
}
a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
p {
    margin: 8px;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible you could elaborate more?

Comment: I am trying to LEARN this, so I can know what to do in the future, and thank you for the help.

Comment: You opened the `div` elements, but you never closed them. The result was nested divs. You had `<div class="left"><div class="centered"><div class="right">` and then the browser filled in the rest for you by adding `</div></div></div>` at the end, which is not at all what you wanted. Also, floats should be placed before the non-floated elements, so the right div should be before the center one.

Comment: Also, here's a simpler way to achieve what you're going for here: http://jsfiddle.net/rfh26/

Comment: Alright, thank you for the info.  I still don't quite have my problem fixed.  But thank you.

Comment: Ok, let me try the simpler way.  then i'll comment on how it was, this looks like it will be perfect.

Comment: Here's the example with your content and formatting filled in. http://jsfiddle.net/rfh26/7/

Comment: Ok, I have edited all my info in.  I don't SEE any errors, and the jsFiddle looks fine. (http://jsfiddle.net/rfh26/14/)
But when I put the HTML and CSS on my website.  It's more jumbled than ever.  D:

Comment: Wait, sorry.  I didn't see your latest comment.

Comment: Ok, I even tried YOUR CSS and HTML.  And it is also jumbled up.  I don't know what I am supposed to do. :'(

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what your looking for

```
     <div style="background-color: Black; width: 100%; height: 680px;">
            <div style="width: 970px; margin: 0 auto;padding:0px">
                <div style="width: 25%; height: 675px; float: left; background-color: Blue;">
                 Left div
                </div>
                <div style="width: 75%; height: 675px; float: right; background-color: white">
                    <div style="width: 75%; height: 675px; float: left; background-color: red">
                    Center Div
                    </div>
                    <div style="width: 25%; height: 675px; float: right; background-color: Green">
                     Right Div
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```